# How to create default options for all controller render calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I'm writing a Rails API using ActiveModel::Serializers.  I am following the JSON API spec and would like to include some data about `current_user` for authorization and authentication in the response's top-level `meta` key.  With ActiveModel::Serializers, top-level meta information is specified like this:

```
render json: @posts, meta: { 'current-user': @current_user }
```

But I would like to have this information available on **all** JSON responses.  It's a big hassle to define this information every single time I call `render` in each of my controllers.

Is there any way I can pass the `meta:` option to *all* my controller's render calls by default, say somewhere in my `ApplicationController` or something?

Answer (score 0):

**Create a def and append to before_action in application controller**

This might work for you

**Create this def in application controller**

```
def append_user_to_json(data)
user = current_user.to_json
data = data.to_json
return data = data+user
end
```

Comment: Can you give a code example?  Because I thought about doing something like that, essentially a custom render method, but that kind of defeats why I've asked this, which was to not have to change the rails generated api controllers.